# How can I prevent the YouTube application from constantly showing a pop-up for YouTube Premium trial?

Tags: youtube

How can I prevent the YouTube application from constantly showing a pop-up for the YouTube Premium trial? I'd like to never have this window.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-stop-YouTube-from-offering-me-YouTube-Premium-even-after-I-say-no-repeatedly) is from Quora:

> Tap “channel icon”, top right hand corner. This will lead to “account”.
>
> Scroll down to “settings”, and select “notifications”.
>
> Scroll down to “Product Updates”, and turn the ‘switch' off by tapping on it. It shall turn grey, and point to the left.
>
> While you're there, you can also change any other settings that may have been bothering you.
>
> This may reset whenever YouTube updates, so remember to switch it off again if the adverts re-appear.

For the past 6-8 months, I have not been using the Youtube app (I prefer [NewPipe](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/releases) to access Youtube). So, I can't confirm if the above suggestions work 100% of the time.

Comment: There is no "Product Updates" or anything similar (anymore).

Comment: Directions seem legit on the current Android app.

Answer (score 1):

I have never been disturbed with these popups so far in the modded YouTube app named YouTube Vanced so I suggest you try this app. The app also has background play feature that can be used without a YouTube Premium subscription.

Head over the XDA thread [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-youtube-vanced-edition-t3758757) to know more about this app and learn about its installation.

Note: the app automatically blocks ads served by YouTube.